# '' is not a subtype of ''

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to pass array of `Note` class as an argument of the function.

`Note` is subclass of `RLMObject`, so in my opinion there should be no problem.

```
private var notesSection = [Note]()

func add(inout sectionArray: [RLMObject]){

}

func addNote(){
    //Here is an error: Cannot invoke 'add' with an argument list 
    //of type '(sectionArray: inout [(Note)])'
    add(sectionArray: &notesSection)
}
```

I also tried to cast array:

```
let castedArray = notesSection as! [RLMObject]
```

But in this case I get an error:

> 'RLMObject' is not a subtype of 'Note'

Answer (score 0):

Swift is strict with types. The solution should be simple.

If you maintain an array with only `Note`s, make sure you add a `Note` object. If you maintain an array with `RLMObject`s, make sure you only add an `RLMObject`.

If your array contains different kind of objects, use `AnyObject`.

I suppose minimal effort for your case would be to use `[RLMObject]` for the `Note` array and then cast whenever you need to use a `Note`.

Finally, it seems you are constructing arrays to populate a table view. Your setup seems rather clumsy and does not take advantage of the `datasource` mechanism of table views. IMO, you do not need a hierarchical structure of nested arrays, especially if the potential number of sections is limited. If you are using Core Data, do consider a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: I use Realm. I changed to AnyObject: ```func add(inout sectionArray: [AnyObject])```, but still have the same error.

Comment: P.S. I use quite complicated table view with edit mode, that's why it's easier to construct that array to show data.

Comment: Why do you need `inout`? Try just adding the array.

Comment: Because that array is used in another delegate methods, like ```commitEditingStyle```, ```didSelectRowAtIndexPath```.

Comment: I have 3 similar sections with different entities, subclassed from ```RLMObject```. What I want to do, is to use DRY principle to have less code when adding one of the entities to the according section.